# Jquery AJax select option is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page which contains autocomplete. i have tried the following code. it works awesome. but issue is select did not fire and alert at all not coming.Please help me to resolve this.

```
$('#w-input-search').autocomplete({

            serviceUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cn/contact/getAccountTags',
            paramName: "tagName",
            delimiter: "," ,
            transformResult: function(response) {

                return {

            suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {

                        return { value: item.tagName, data: item.id };
             } )

                };

            },
           select: function(event, ui) {
              alert("");
            }


        });
   $( "#w-input-search" ).on("autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
          alert("");
  } );
```

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Create demo that reproduces issue. See [mcve]

Comment: What is `serviceUrl`? Are you using jQuery UI Autocomplete or something else? Please use proper tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct configuration is `onSelect` and not `select`. I suppose you are using [Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)

From the docs:

> `onSelect`: `function (suggestion) {}` Callback function invoked when user selects suggestion from the list. `this` inside callback refers to input HtmlElement.